# Finding the relation between powers from $V$-$I$ graph

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, power

[image]

> Clearly, resistance of A is greater than that of B. So, my teacher told me, Heat is directly proportional to resistance, hence, the answer is A. However, what I thought was heat is indeed directly proportional to resistance FOR A GIVEN CURRENT. In this case, since the wires are connected to a same battery,it is the voltage that'll remain constant. And, $H=V^2t/R$. Hence, heat/power will be indirectly proportional to R and the answer will be B.
>
> Who exactly is wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: Are they saying the answer is  A?

Comment: And it’s not clear what they mean by connecting “both wires one by one”.

Comment: I think they are connected separately. First, only A. And then, only B.

Comment: Atleast my teacher is. He was actually convinced by my method, but then he just beat around the bush, concluding the answer is A.

Comment: I think your mentor also gone through the same confusion about PV and VI that's why it might happen. But the final answer will be B as it can clearly be concluded from the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a pure resistor power is the product of voltage and current. From the graph it is clear for a given voltage the product of voltage and current is greater for B.

Also, for a pure resistor power is the square of the voltage divided by the resistance. For a given voltage the power is greater the lower the resistance. That’s again the case for B..

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Wires are directly connected to battery doesn't give an exact notion of what does it actually represent i.e is it parallel or series. If it's a parallel combination that means the voltage drop across each resistance is same and for a basic circuit the wire should be directly connected to the battery as well.

Now coming to your question, it's been asked that the load is connected and tested one by one that means the current will differ in both the cases as you have different value of resistance, so it might get complicated to compare the power dissipated with the help of the corresponding values of current. So for such types circuits in which the potential difference applied across the resistance is same it's a better idea to compare the powers using,

$P=\frac{V^2}{R}$

So hence that's why it will dissipate more power when the fraction $\frac{1}{R}$ is bigger that means the resistance is smaller which you can clearly conclude from the graph provided to you.

And according to the conclusion made above the correct answer must be B.

Comment: Lesser the resistance, greater the power. Then, the answer should be B, right?

Comment: Oh I think I read your question incorrectly the graph is about $VI$ not $PV$ thanks for pointing it out. And yes B is the correct answer as you said.